# How to send OSC commands from iPad/iPhone over the Internet (not Wi-Fi)

Tags: iphone, ipad, arduino, osc

I am building an Arduino based servo driver that I want to control with [OSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_Control) commands from my iPad over the Internet.

Is it possible to send OSC commands over 3G / UMTS with my iPad or iPhone to control a device? So I will not be limited by the router's range when I send OSC commands to the controller when both devices are part of the same Wi-Fi network.

It seems that the applications I downloaded ([TouchOSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_Control#Implementations), iOSC) can only send OSC data over Wi-Fi, however I'd like to send the commands over the Internet (with port forwarding settings in my router).

Comment: It's not immediately obvious what you mean by "OSC". Given the sample apps that you named, am I correct in assuming you want "Open Sound Control"?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I want to use the "Open Sound Control" protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Do port forwarding on your router to forward port x to the Arduino, and then use the IP address from `whatsmyip.com` and use that one in the touchOSC app when inputting the IP address. That may work.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried. It only works when my iPhone or iPad is connected via Wi-fi. If I disable wi-fi then it doesn't seem to be possible to send OSC messages with TouchOSC.

Comment: For some reason all the "open sound control" apps can only send OSC data over wi-fi. What I want is sending OSC commands with my iPhone over Internet so I can control my OSC receiver from anywhere without the limitation of my wi-fi area.

Comment: How is your arduino connected to the Internet?

Comment: Arduino is connected to my router, with a fixed IP. With TouchOSC I can reach the Arduino (with port forwarding enabled) but only if my iPad/iPhone is connected to wi-fi. So the problem seems to be the app which cannot send OSC without being attached to a wi-fi network.

Comment: I wonder if you were to jailbreak your iphone and download an app that makes the phone think its on wifi if this would then work. They have these so you could do VOIP calls over 3G, so may be worth a shot if your already jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

I would get one of [these](http://www.cutedigi.com/product_info.php?products_id=4424&osCsid=8af1b9c646bd5438102ed78202718a68). Look ma, no wi-fi :)

Answer (score 0):

OSC typically uses UDP (User Datagram Protocol), even if some newer OSC implementations also allow TCP/IP messaging (also see [Difference between TCP and UDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970383/difference-between-tcp-and-udp)).

Unfortunately (as far as I know), **UDP does not work over 3G**, which seems to be your problem. In other words: two mobile devices cannot talk to each other on a cellular network. So it has nothing to do with OSC apps not being able to do this, it's just not available from the cellular network.

However (I think, not tested), I see two workarounds here:

- try to use TCP/IP instead of UDP to send your OSC packets
- if you need UDP on the Arduino side, you could use a server in-between