# I'm confused on terminology about wifi

Tags: tcp, udp, wifi, terminology

I am trying to simulate a wifi video transmission and for that I created a connection using a socket between 2 devices, however I then started to doubt whether this is required or if I was supposed to create a UDP connection.

I think I'm just confused on terms here and I've Googled and I found out that Wifi can has TCP or UDP my question would then be would a Wifi Transmission over TCP be as reliable for a simulation as one with UDP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to read [Difference between TCP and UDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970383/difference-between-tcp-and-udp).

For streaming like video transmission you would generally want to use UDP. If a packet cannot reach the server in time, it'd better be discarded than pausing the whole transmission in order to wait for one tiny missing packet that just contains the other person blinking.

But obviously it's up to you and how you implement your software.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to read up a bit on the TCP/IP protocol. TCP and UDP are just types of packets/datagrams. The main difference is that TCP packets include extra protocol information, whereas UDP are simpler packets with just a destination, the data itself, and a checksum.

The upshot is that the sender of a UDP packet has no way of knowing whether or not the packet was received at the other end. Often this doesn't matter - because it may be handled in other ways by higher layers in the software, or can be simply lost and ignored without any negative consequences. So UDP can be a more efficient use of the bandwidth, in some scenarios - because there is less protocol information being exchanged, and therefore more actual data. Plus TCP is more complicated because you have to handle the protocol stuff.

So when you create your system, you have a choice - either TCP or UDP packets, depending on what you are trying to achieve and how you want to go about it. But both packet types are really all part of the "tcp/ip" protocol stack, and have similarities.