# Difference between TCP and UDP

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

Hello guys I am still new to the network world and just wanted to ask if someone could explain to me briefly the difference between TCP and UDP.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tcp%20vs%20udp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between TCP and UDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970383/difference-between-tcp-and-udp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is more reliable, if all data must be sent without corruption it's a better choice because it has acknowledgment system (Promising the other side received the data)
UDP is for sending the data faster with the risk of losing some parts.It Has no acknowledgment system and the other side might miss some parts of the transferred data. Common protocol for media over the network.

Answer (score 0):

TCP:

1. transmission control protocol.
2. connection oriented.
3. reliable.
4. manage flow control.
5. costly as compared to UDP.
6. state full.
7. maintain sequence number.
8. acknowledgement.
9. FTP,SMTP,TELNET,RPC,BOOTP.

UDP:

1. user datagram protocol.
2. connection less.
3. unreliable.
4. does not manage flow control.
5. cheap as compared to UDP.
6. state less.
7. maintain sequence number is not done in UDP.
8. no acknowledgement facility.
9. SNMP,TFTP,NTP,NTP.