# Difference between TCP and UDP sockets

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

What is the difference between making a connection with TCP sockets (sock_stream) and UDP sockets (datagram). Up to now, I think like
we can create a connection using connect function only for TCP sockets. But, it is possible for making a connection with UDP sockets.
Up to now I didn't know about making a connection with UDP sockets. What is the difference between these two?

```
        int tcpsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        connect(tcpsock,(struct sockaddr*)&sa,sizeof(sa));

        int udpsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        connect(udpsock,(struct sockaddr*)&sa,sizeof(sa));  // How ?
```

UDP is connectionless. so if we use UDP how it is possible to make a connection similar to TCP?

I already know about the difference between TCP and UDP. My doubt is, UDP is
connectionless then how connect function returns success?

Comment: Why the C and C++ tags are there?

Comment: Have you tried typing ["difference between TCP and UDP"](http://google.com/search?q=difference+between+tcp+and+udp) into Google, and then reading some of the results?

Comment: _"Up to now, I think like we can create a connection using connect function only for tcp socket."_ Well, that's because the TCP protocol requires that. The UDP protocol is connectionless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between TCP and UDP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970383/difference-between-tcp-and-udp)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But connect function returns 0(success) even for udp sockets.

Comment: What part of the *man* page didn't you understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `connect()` function in UDP (a) tells UDP where to send all datagrams, so you can use `send()` instead of `sendto()`, and (b) acts as a filter on incoming datagrams, so you can use `recv()` instead of `recvfrom()`. It doesn't do anything on the network: it's just a local operation. It always returns zero because it can't fail. However sending to a non-existent target can fail ...

It's all documented.