# Can I use QUdpSocket to conect with QTcpServer?

Tags: qtcpserver, qt5.7, qudpsocket

I am super new to the networking world, so I have a QTcpserver that's currently working with the newConnection signal, but I was wondering if I could use QUdpSocket with a QTcpServer ? It's this possible at all ?

Comment: Nope. UDP does not even have the concept of "connecting". A QTcpSocket should work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TCP is a connection oriented stream over an IP network. It guarantees
>   that all sent packets will reach the destination in the correct order.
>   This imply the use of acknowledgement packets sent back to the sender,
>   and automatic retransmission, causing additional delays and a general
>   less efficient transmission than UDP.
>
> UDP is a connection-less protocol. Communication is datagram oriented.
>   The integrity is guaranteed only on the single datagram. Datagrams
>   reach destination and can arrive out of order or don't arrive at all.
>   It is more efficient than TCP because it uses non ACK. It's generally
>   used for real time communication, where a little percentage of packet
>   loss rate is preferable to the overhead of a TCP connection.
>   [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970545/6182948)

So the simple Answer is No , You can't ,because tcp and udp are 2 different protocols .