# Unable to establish calls with Freeswitch sometimes

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch, linphone

I am making video calls from Linphone to linphone on android.Both the mobile apps are successfully registered on Freeswitch server.

But  when i  make a call it does't get established.It is happening randomly only.When i checked dump on server i found that Freeswitch keeps sending Invite on B leg side but does't get any response for invite.There are also multiple sip uri's in invite.

Can somebody help me with this?
Is there anything related to server configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Correction--
there were multiple invites with different sip uris.Different port and ips.

Comment: I also found that this is happening over udp connection.

Comment: It might be the case that your device's network condition is not stable, thus changing IP/port frequently. Or perhaps your device is behind some NAT that's messing up things. You can try shorten the expire time of your session so that your device re-registers more frequently.

Comment: I am testing my calls on linphone mobile app on android over various mobile data network and sometimes does't get established.

Comment: I have also tried making calls just after sending the registeration packet but failed but when i changed it to tcp it worked for me.

Comment: Good to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

It's frequent, call over UDP doesn't work.
Try with TCP and normally it's must work correctly.

For more information about the difference between TCP and UDP look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970545/7131120

Comment: Is there anything related to blockage due to ALG's of mobile network specially on UDP even though my app over mobile data is getting registered but call is not coming.